# Result not showing when button is clicked - HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problems with my code. When I try to click the button, the result is not showing. I think my button is not working, or my js code is wrong.

```js
function val() {
  var g = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textvalue").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = g + "g is " + (g / 1000) + " kg";
};
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-12">
        <h1>convert grams(g) to kilograms(kg) </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter mb-5">
          <input type="string" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value" id="textvalue">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-1" id="cnvrtbutton" onclick="val()">Convert</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="resultcol">
        <p id="result"> Result is here!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is running fine here, so what is different?

Comment: works as expected in code snippet

Comment: When you run code snippet its seems to working. 
If its doesn't run in your application , maybe you don't export or import the function to html or vice versa.

Comment: It's working now, thank you for your help! It was my javascript path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste below code into your HTML file and it should work fine (as it is working fine in your question).
I think you might not be linking the JS file correctly so suggestion you to just include the JS code in HTML file.

```
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <h1>convert grams(g) to kilograms(kg) </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container" id="main-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="input-group input-group-newsletter mb-5">
              <input type="string" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value" id="textvalue">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark mt-1" id="cnvrtbutton" onclick="val()">Convert</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col" id="resultcol">
            <p id="result"> Result is here!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   <script>
    function val() {
      var g = parseFloat(document.getElementById("textvalue").value);
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = g + "g is " + (g / 1000) + " kg";
    };
</script>
```